# React - How to Pass an Argument to an Event Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, so I'm new to React, and there is one thing about event handlers that is really, really bothering me: I can't seem to get a straight answer about how to pass arguments to them. So far, there are two ways that I've seen:

Bind

```
props.squareClick.bind(this, argument)
```

Inline

```
onClick={() => props.squareClick(argument)}
```

The big thing I keep reading about is performance costs. Because inline functions or functions with Bind get treated as brand new functions on a re-render, there's extra GC overhead and, for class components, it can break shallow checks for shouldComponentRender with PureComponent.

Then there are some people saying this is over-optimization, that I shouldn't worry about it and just use an inline function. Which is cool, but honestly all of this conflicting information is leaving me confused.

So, I'm going to include a code example. It's take from a Tic-Tac-Toe app I made to practice React. It is a functional component for a single Square on the board. This component is re-used for all of the squares, and a key is passed in as a prop (ie, TOP_LEFT) to indicate which square it is. There's also a click handler where when the Square is clicked on, an event is sent back to the parent component. For the click handler to know which Square was clicked, that key property is passed in as an argument.

Please look at this code and give me feedback. Is this an acceptable practice in React? Will it incur a performance hit, and will that performance hit be substantial? Finally, if your answer is that I shouldn't do this, please clearly explain to me a better practice.

```
import React from 'react';

const Square = props => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => props.squareClick(props.key)}>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Square;
```

Comment: If you have a lot of such square component which keep on updating very frequently then you need to worry about a performance hit, otherwise you can use inline arrow function. However its better that you follow it as a practise to avoid using inline arrow functions since as your app grows it will become difficult to solve such performance issues. Check this on how you can avoid such scenarios https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753

Answer (score 9):

What I usually do is using [datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
import React from 'react';

const Square = props => {
    return (
        <div
          data-key={props.key}
          onClick={props.squareClick}>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Square;
```

Then on the method itself, you just get back your value as `e.target.dataset.key`.

Or you could also turn it to a class component :

```
import React from 'react';

class Square extends React.Component {
    handleClick = e => {
      this.props.squareClick(this.props.key)
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <p>{this.props.value}</p>
          </div>
      );
    }
};

export default Square;
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I did not know that there was a dataset property on the target object. I have also used data attributes, but with e.target.getAttribute('data-key')

Comment: Nice approach with datasets. For this example OP doesn't need it or need to convert the component to a class since there is props provided here. But for other situations datasets could be very useful. Edit: with datasets OP doesn't need a handle function of course. One advantage is this.

Answer (score 1):

In React with Typescript to pass extra parameter to an event handler I do like this :

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p onClick={(this.handleClick("Volvo"))}>Volvo</p>
                <p onClick={this.handleClick("Saab")} >Saab</p>
                <p onClick={this.handleClick("Mercedes")} >Mercedes</p>
                <p onClick={this.handleClick("Audi")} >Audi</p>
                <div id="selectResult">
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick(selected: string): ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) {
        return (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("selectResult")!.innerHTML = "You clicked: " + selected;
        }
    }

}
```

**Also see the project for this example in** [Codpen](https://codepen.io/namik-hajiyev/pen/xxbJWzE)

Answer (score 0):

For your example this can be used:

```
import React from 'react';

const Square = props => {
    const handleClick = () => props.squareClick(props.key);
    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Square;
```

With this method, just using reference for a function, function itself won't recreated every time. But, for some situations people can't use a method something like this and seeking other solutions. There are multiple questions around here like this:

[How to pass variables to a function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630902/how-to-pass-variables-to-a-function-reference/50631924#50631924)